# SSRS 2012 CustomReportItems: ReportServerException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed

Tags: reporting-services

I have implemented CustomReportItems in SSRS, it works fine in all scenarios while deployed on a reportserver except when it takes more than 2:15 minutes to save a report to pdf, amazing thing is if i render my report in designer mode i.e from visual studio it works fine even for those report which take more than 2 hours to render.

I have tried following things to fix the issue.

1) http://www.avyuktasolutions.com/blog/sql-server-reporting-services-timeout-settings/     Almost all timeouts in the mentioned link.
2) Thread abort exception is thrwon exactly after 2 min 15 sec.

**Exception on Browser**

```
    Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed. 
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.]
   System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +1321
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.ServerUrlRequest(AbortState abortState, String url, Stream outputStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension) +649
```

**Exception in Log**

```
processing!ReportServer_0-2!212c!10/12/2015-19:03:50:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: An error has occurred during processing of the CustomReportItem 'PVCharts1' with the 'PVCharts' extension. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PVChartsCRI.PVCRI.DrawImage(CustomReportItem customReportItem)
   at PVChartsCRI.PVCRI.EvaluateReportItemInstance(CustomReportItem cri)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.CustomReportItem.EvaluateGeneratedReportItemInstance()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
library!ReportServer_0-2!212c!10/12/2015-19:03:51:: w WARN: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: An error has occurred during processing of the CustomReportItem 'PVCharts1' with the 'PVCharts' extension. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: An error has occurred during processing of the CustomReportItem 'PVCharts1' with the 'PVCharts' extension. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
webserver!ReportServer_0-2!212c!10/12/2015-19:03:51:: e ERROR: Reporting Services error Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: An error has occurred during processing of the CustomReportItem 'PVCharts1' with the 'PVCharts' extension. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: An error has occurred during processing of the CustomReportItem 'PVCharts1' with the 'PVCharts' extension. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: An error has occurred during processing of the CustomReportItem 'PVCharts1' with the 'PVCharts' extension. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
library!ReportServer_0-2!212c!10/12/2015-19:03:51:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeException: The request has been aborted., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeException: An error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-2-130891320078579635. Most likely, the HTTP request contains an unsupported verb or invalid syntax. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
ui!ReportManager_0-1!22fc!10/12/2015-19:03:51:: i INFO: Unhandled exception: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.ServerUrlRequest(AbortState abortState, String url, Stream outputStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.ServerUrlRequest(AbortState abortState, String url, Stream outputStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.Render(AbortState abortState, String reportPath, String executionId, String historyId, String format, XmlNodeList deviceInfo, NameValueCollection urlAccessParameters, Stream reportStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.InternalRender(Boolean isAbortable, String format, String deviceInfo, NameValueCollection urlAccessParameters, Stream reportStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerModeSession.RenderReport(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, NameValueCollection additionalParams, Boolean cacheSecondaryStreamsForHtml, String& mimeType, String& fileExtension)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ExportOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Have you tried Turn Off the Windows Firewall? Turn Off the Antivirus? if this will help? Your slow internet connection might also be the culprit. also try to read this post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1543a3cb-5d31-49ed-bc40-a01815ab70a3/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send?forum=sqlreportingservices its related to 'SecureConnectionLevel'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue my self. Actually during execution of report i was writing log in bin folder. I don't know why but after around 2 minutes thread was aborted by the process. I simply changed the directory with out changing anything configuration. It is working fine now.